# Can a bash script terminate without killing any apps it may have started?

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script that (among other things) starts the image viewer xv.

Is there any way the script can terminate without killing xv?

I want to get the script to do this, it is not a problem it has that I'm trying to fix.

Comment: Just run it in the background with `xv &`. The script can then exit and `xv` will keep running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nohup` to start the applications.

```
nohup xv
```

https://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm

> When using the command shell, prefixing a command with nohup prevents the command from being aborted automatically when you log out or exit the shell.
>
> The name nohup stands for "no hangup." The hangup (HUP) signal, which is normally sent to a process to inform it that the user has logged off (or "hung up"), is intercepted by nohup, allowing the process to continue running.

Comment: It should be `nohup xv &`. Using nohup with foreground commands is pretty pointless, especially in scripts...